# blank space at the bottom html5 jquery

Tags: jquery, ios, html

I have been trying to find the answer with stackoverflow, and with google, but still can not solve my problem.

Here it is: I am working with jquery, when I use Safari - iPhone 3Gs to open my app, there is always a blank space at the bottom of the screen. I can not remove it. :(

The code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/XxB6Y/17/
And here is full code with images: http://www.mediafire.com/?bds0xgnzxki22ww

And one more thing I can not understand is when I use a REAL Iphone to test my App, and switch to view12 (id: contentView12) or view22 (id: contentView22) , the input textfield appears differently (underneath the picture) with the thing that appears when I use simulator to test. :(

Thank you so so so much.

Comment: Is it possible the white space is because you specified a fixed height?

Comment: yes, I suspected the "fixed" property, but still can not make it clear. :(

Answer (score 1):

Your calculated heights are incorrect, I guess. I played a bit with your code and there's no whitespace now:

http://jsfiddle.net/XxB6Y/18/

Can you tell what should be the final total height so I can calculate correct numbers?

Comment: Dear Ihor - paspar2.com,

Well, I have just tried your code, but still "blank space" with both simulator and REAL iPhone. :(

The height of the body tag is:416px.

Thanks in advanced. :)

Comment: oh, I can't test jsfiddle on my iPhone ) Tried only in browser and it was removed. Will try to figure it out but no promises. Hope someone will help you.

Comment: Here is my full code: http://www.mediafire.com/?bds0xgnzxki22ww

Again, thank you for taking a look at my problem. :)